# How to invoke an intent through a custom event by calling it from the dialogflow's inline fulfillment code?

Tags: firebase, events, webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Here is the image link of my problem statement better explained through a flow. 
[problem statement flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvGOJ.png)
I couldn't understand How this can be achieved. 
Just starting with web-hooks and dialog flow.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you probably don't want or need to trigger a different Intent.

Remember - Intents should match the *user's input* (usually what they say), not necessarily what you do or how you reply.

If you need to access the database for certain values - access it in the webhook for the Intent where you get the value. If you need to reply certain ways for some values and different ways for others - go ahead and do it.

Comment: I know but this is a special case

Comment: You need to evaluate your own requirements, but neither your problem description nor your diagram illustrate why triggering a different intent would be necessary.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear earlier. I want this because I want google home to speak not only through a conversation aka voice input/text but also when something changes in the firebase DB. I hope this makes it clearer

Comment: I have the rewritten the question to a [new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532915/how-to-make-a-dialogflow-google-agent-respond-and-acknowledge-on-firebases-fiel). Please let me know if I need to clarify more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conv.followup](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.dialogflowconversation.html#followup) in your dialogflow fulfillment to invoke the intent with custom event as below :

```
database().ref('/path').on('value', function(snapshot) {

  if(snapshot.val == 'val'){

         conv.followup('triggering-event'); //enter your event name here
         // make sure you have defined the event in the intent to trigger !

  }

});
```

Consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51784759/6763544) before dealing with intents.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll try this as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: How can I do `conv.followup('custon_event_from_a_separate_intent')` when this is not inside an intent callback itself but inside a separate callback like the firebase watch function?

Comment: I have the rewritten the question to a [new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532915/how-to-make-a-dialogflow-google-agent-respond-and-acknowledge-on-firebases-fiel). Please let me know if I need to clarify more. Thanks. –

Comment: it says conv.followup is not a function. Any help?